# Set binary data using setblob in mysql connector/c++ causes crash

Tags: c++, mysql, binary-data

I tried to use setBlob() as follows:

```
class DataBuf : public streambuf
{
public:
   DataBuf(char * d, size_t s) {
      setg(d, d, d + s);
   }
};


char b[20];
DataBuf buffer((char*)b, 20);
istream stream(&buffer);

PreparedStatement* s = con->PrepareStatement("insert into mytable (mybin) values (?)");
s->setBlob(1, &stream);
int rows = s->executeUpdate();
```

This crashes at executeUpdate(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a hard crash or do any error messages show up? Does the debugger catch anything?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it isn't crashing on:

```
s->setBlob(1, &stream);
```

Check the debugger to make sure that s isn't NULL, or a crap value.

Comment: No, Im stepping through line by line. Crashes in non-debug mode too.