# MySQL C++ Connector crashes executing INSERT with BLOB

Tags: c++, blob, mysql-connector

I've stuck with a problem, trying to insert text as blob value, MySQL C++ connector crashed with exception: "Access violation reading location". I've seen questions like this here, but none has been answered. Here is a code sample:

```
 #include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace sql;

void main(){
    Connection  *dbConnection;
    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "");
    Statement *stmt = con->createStatement();
    try{
        stmt->execute("USE test");
        stmt->execute("DROP TABLE blob_test");
        stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE blob_test("
                        "id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                        "original   BLOB NOT NULL);");
        char smallBlob[32];

        for (char i = 0; i < sizeof(smallBlob); ++i)
        {
        smallBlob[i] = i;
        }
        std::istringstream str(smallBlob);
        PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO blob_test(id, original) VALUES (1, ?)");

        pstmt->setBlob( 1, &str);
        pstmt->executeUpdate();
    }catch(sql::SQLException &e){
        std::cerr << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cerr << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cerr << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `main` function does not return `void`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's just a sample. And it's crashed on the line pstmt->executeUpdate(); I use VS2010

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121142/set-binary-data-using-setblob-in-mysql-connector-c-causes-crash.  I suspect that you do not really want to use istringstream as that operates on strings.  E.g., your smallBlob[0] is a NULL.  So, you may actually be inserting NULL data.  Doesn't explain the crash, I know.

Comment: At which line does it crash?  Did you put a breakpoint inside the `catch` statement?

Comment: @Blazes: I've seen the question you gave, I think I meet with the same problem and there was no answer. Thank you for your point that [0] element of the array is null, I've changed the line to smallBlob[i] = 50 + i; and now smallBlob contains '23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ' according to debug info before crash. To Thomas Mattews: Catch statement haven't reached, because exception is unhandled: Unhandled exception at 0x74d3eab7 in testMySQLblob.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @DenisMakarskiy, I need to check the obvious - are you sure pstmt is not NULL?  Also, my point about the example is that you should probably use something other than istringstream for binary data.  I cannot find the MySQL doc for pstmt->setBlob, so I assume it is a pointer to istream or similar.

Comment: @Blazes I think if pstmt had been NULL, line pstmt->setBlob( 1, &str); wouldn't executed. But program crashed only on the line: pstmt->executeUpdate(); I've tried pass to setBlob istream - result is the same. I got this sample from regression test of MySQL modified it a little bit [link](http://mysql-connector-cplus-pplus-p.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.0~r814-1/BlobRegressionTest_8cpp-source.html) very strange that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved compiling MySQL cpp connector from sources.

If you go that way read carefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111664/how-to-add-mysql-connector-c-1-1-to-visual-studio-2010-project) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) (specially comments in the end). I also had to changed a couple of lines in config.h to implicit cast of int to char*. Also be attentive don't mix Debug and Release, for example if you compile your application in Debug, you should link Debug version of MySQL connector and vice-a-verse.

After I linked lib that I had compiled everything launched )
You may read on dev.mysql.com forums that in most cases it's the only way force the connector to work. While compiling I met with the thing that prove this, include files in source code is different from includes in windows binary distributive.